# Get GridFS files within ids with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I am using MongoDB GridFS to store some user avatars. My backend is PHP.

On some page I need to display all images with single user. So I have the Mongo IDs. How do I perform a find query where _id is in given IDs. In mongo the query would be `{"_id: {$in: [id1,id2]}`. 
In PHP I have:

```
$gridFs = $this->getGridFs();
$photos = $gridFs->find();
```

where find accepts 2 arrays. If I was finding single file it would be:

```
$photos = $gridFs->find(array('id' => new MongoId($id)));
```

So what about several results?
And also I wander if it is possible to find with limit and offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MongoGridFS::find()](http://php.net/mongogridfs.find) returns a [MongoGridFSCursor](http://php.net/class.mongogridfscursor), which extends [MongoCursor](http://php.net/class.mongocursor).
[->skip()](http://php.net/mongocursor.skip) and [->limit()](http://php.net/mongocursor.limit) are available on the MongoCursor.

The MongoGridFS::find() syntax is the same as the [MongoCollection::find() syntax](http://php.net/mongocollection.find#refsect1-mongocollection.find-examples).

```
$MongoGridFSCursor = $MongoGridFSObject->find(array(
    'id' => array('$in' => array($myMongoID1, $myMongoID2))
));
```

You can then skip over some results and limit them:

```
$MongoGridFSCursor->skip(3)->limit(8);
```

and finally iterate over the results:

```
foreach($MongoGridFSCursor as $MongoGridFSFile) {
}
```

I suspect your example is incorrect, and should be _id, not id, in your find query?